# How can this guy copy and paste UVs?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

[image]

Im trying to follow this tutorial but the guy is able o copy and paste UVs by pressing the U key in edit mode? How is he able to do this? here is the link too the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rhq9SDPB9ik

Comment: It is a default add-on called "Magic UV" (search in User Prefs)